# How do I include endpoints with query params when configuring requestMatchers in Spring security 6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, auth0

I have the following code...

```java
import com.purepm.admin.services.authentication.AudienceValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/person").hasAuthority("SCOPE_blahablah")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But when I use the following command to run the request `curl http://localhost:8080/person -v` I see the expected 403...

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /person HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=EFD9C400D91760FE8FA2119AC2EB382B; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2023 21:45:16 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

This is as expected since I am not providing an Authorization header (Although I would expect a 401).

But when I add the query param like `curl http://localhost:8080/person?email=me@me.co` it just lets it right through and I get a 200. Is there a way to use the query string to enforce the 403 when there is a query param as well?

Comment: The `/person` should already match. I suspect it is due to you are adding params directly in the URL instead of passing them as parameters for the request. You should do `curl http://localhost:8080/person -d "email=me@me.co"`. That will add it as a parameter, else it will be treated as a URL by cUrl and encoded and thus you will fallthrough to the `anyRequest().authenticated()`. So the problem is not the Spring Secuirty config but your cUrl usage.

Comment: So this is saying I cannot use Query parameters with Spring Security?

Comment: You don't need to, and the curl request was wrong as it was using what you had as the full URL (curl will encode it as a full url and not as a URL with query parameters).

Comment: Not sure I am sure I follow both curl and commands work on bash. you have to wrap in a quote on ZShell but I confirmed both commands work